# Can Java accomplish this toolbar for a Mac app?

Tags: java, macos, toolbar, custom-titlebar

Has anyone accomplished this toolbar for Mac app using Java?

[image: Mac app toolbar with Java]

Basically, what I would like to do is to get rid of the title, bind the toolbar with toolbar menu items to the left and bind the search field to the right with fullscreen button.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this question which is somehow similar :

[Java Swing Mac OSX Title Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746148/java-swing-mac-osx-title-bar)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I tried that "Mac Widgets for Java". No luck!

Comment: You're welcome, I thought the unified toolbar of http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/ was pretty close to what you requested.

Comment: Sure it is, but I still cannot figure out how to move those buttons up :(

Comment: it isn't exactly - the widgets are not part of the 'border' of the window. I suspect you will need to do native calls and thus make your app non-portable to other OSes. Might as well write the app in objective-c, and use cocoa (or what ever the UI framework is called for macs). see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665147/how-to-custom-draw-window-title-bar-in-objective-c

Comment: I wish I could, but I am so "Java" at this time. I guess the only way to do it is by using borderless window and completely draw the toolbar with traffic buttons again.